# Write data in Excel using POI. It delete my entire WorkBook?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am new in Selenium. I am trying to write data in Excel file, by getting activeRow and search the column Heading.

My Code in Driver Script Class is like :

```
int activeRow = cnfig.isScenarioAvailable("New", cn);
    if (activeRow != 0) {
        String[] colHeading = new String[cnfig.getcolumnCount("New")];
        colHeading = cnfig.getcolumnHeadinginArray("New");

for (int counter = 0; counter < cnfig.getcolumnCount("New"); counter++) {
    if (colHeading[counter].equals("Name")) {
        inName = cn + " Test" + cmnfnc.getRandomNumber(5000, 100);
        cnfig.setData(activeRow, counter, "Name", inName);
    }
```

And The Code in my Config Class is

```
 XSSFWorkbook wb;
 XSSFSheet sht;

 File fl;
 FileInputStream fis;
 FileOutputStream fout;

 public ExcelConfig(String filePath) {
    try {
        fl = new File(filePath);
        fis = new FileInputStream(fl);
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        fout = new FileOutputStream(fl);

    } 

public void setData(int activeRow, int activeCol, String sheetName, String value) {
    try {
        sht = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
        sht.getRow(activeRow).createCell(activeCol).setCellValue(value);
        wb.write(fout);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a selenium question kindly remove the selenium tag.

If you want to edit an excel workbook with poi you must 1st load your file inputstream

```
public void setData(int activeRow, int activeCol, String sheetName, String value) {

    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(yourFileLocation);
        XSSFWorkbook wb    = new XSSFWorkbook(in);  //I know this line is not suppose to be here, but I hope you get the general idea
        sht                = wb.getSheet(sheetName);

        sht.getRow(activeRow).createCell(activeCol).setCellValue(value);
        wb.write(fout);
    }
}
```

Comment: I define these Globally  in my code :                                                           FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(yourFileLocation);
XSSFWorkbook wb    = new XSSFWorkbook(in);

Comment: if you have already set the inputstream, then it is likely that your code have overridden the workbook original data. can you post the code where you create row?